# How to setup a linked server to Access 2000 database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2000

I am using SQL 2005 Server Express.
How can I setup a linked server to an MS Access 2000 database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) in Books Online.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
  @server     = 'linked server name',
  @srvproduct = 'Access',
  @provider   = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
  @datasrc    = 'C:\path\file.MDB';
```

You may also need to use sp_addlinkedsrvlogin to associate a user/login with the linked server.  Also, if you are using Access 2007, you may need to use an alternate provider:

```
  @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
```

And finally, if you are on a 64-bit operating system, you may run into issues.